# Fazer script que determine uma coluna pretendida

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Bom dia!
Estou a tentar fazer um script em que fazendo 2 joins, ele me mostre 3 colunas.
Ou seja, o que pretendo é obter o `email do lider`. Porém ele não tem uma coluna em específico, está inserido o seu email na coluna `Email Lider`, e lá também estão os `emails do gestores`.

Deveria aparecer desta forma:

```
ID | Email Gestor | Email Lider
-------------------------------
13 | pd@ssss.com  | lider@ssss.com
14 | pf@ssss.com  | lider2@ssss.com
15 | fp@ssss.com  | lider2@ssss.com
16 | fd@ssss.com  | lider@ssss.com
17 | ff@ssss.com  | lider2@ssss.com
18 | gg@ssss.com  | lider@ssss.com
```

O problema é que eu não estou a conseguir encontrar o código certo para isso. E portanto o resultado que obtenho é este:

```
ID | Email Gestor | Email Lider
-------------------------------
13 | pd@ssss.com  | hh@ssss.com
14 | pf@ssss.com  | ee@ssss.com
15 | fp@ssss.com  | gt@ssss.com
16 | fd@ssss.com  | ww@ssss.com
17 | ff@ssss.com  | kl@ssss.com
18 | gg@ssss.com  | as@ssss.com
```

Ou seja, em vez de obter os mails do lideres, obtenho emails de gestores.

A tabela para is buscar o nome dos lideres é basicamente assim:

```
-- Tabelas que estou a fazer consulta:
-- Tabela Tecnicos S --

    IDGestor | NomeGestor | Email
    ----------------------------------------
    13       | pd         | hh@ssss.com    |
    14       | pf         | ee@ssss.com    |
    15       | fp         | gt@ssss.com    |
    16       | fd         | ww@ssss.com    |
    17       | ff         | kl@ssss.com    |
    18       | gg         | as@ssss.com    |
    19       | lider      | lider@ssss.com |
    20       | lider2     | lider@ssss.com |

-- Tabela Reclamaçoes R --

IDGestor   | Resolvido |
-----------------------
13         |     0     | 
14         |     0     | 
15         |     0     | 
16         |     0     | 
17         |     0     | 
18         |     0     | 
19         |     0     | 
20         |     0     | 

-- Tabela Vendedor S --


        IDGestor   | NomeGestor |
        ------------------------
        13         |     pd     | 
        14         |     pf     | 
        15         |     fp     | 
        16         |     fd     | 
        17         |     ff     | 
        18         |     gg     | 
        19         |    lider   | 
        20         |   lider2   |
```

Ou seja as colunas fazem ligação entre si:
Reclamações com Vendedor: Id Gestor
Reclamações com Tecnico : Id Gestor
Vendedor com Tecnico    : Id Gestor e Nome Gestor

O código que eu tenho é este:

```
SELECT R.ID
    ,VS.Email AS EmailGestor
    ,TS.email AS EmailLider
FROM dbo.Reclamacoes R
INNER JOIN dbo.TECNICOS_S TS ON R.IdGestor = TS.IdTecnico
INNER JOIN dbo.VENDEDORES_S VS ON R.IdGestor = VS.IdVendedor
WHERE R.Resolvido = 0
ORDER BY R.ID
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?
Qualquer dúvida para entender o que pretendo saber, não exite em perguntar.
Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Como sabe a diferença entre gestor e líder? Edite a sua questão e coloque a estrutura das tabelas que está a utilizar na consulta.

Comment: @JoãoMartins já foram feitas alterações, consegue assim perceber?
A diferença entre o gestor é que o gestor tem o nome "pf" por exemplo, só 2 letras. o lider tem mesmo o nome "lider" por exemplo.

Comment: Se está a ligar a tabela `Reclamacoes` pela coluna `IdGestor` à tabela `TECNICOS_S` pela coluna `IdTecnico` (que na estrutura que colocou imagino que corresponda à `IDGestor`) então não conseguirá ter o email do líder, porque está a associar pelo ID, que lhe traz sempre o email associado a esse ID, e não outro qualquer associado a um líder.

Comment: @JoãoMartins então como faço para obter esse email?

Comment: Aí se calha terá que criar uma coluna que associe o gestor a um líder.

Comment: criar uma coluna ou fazer um select? 
a base de dados é da empresa onde estou a estagiar, não posso nem tenho permissões para criar colunas nas tabelas.

Comment: Com essa estrutura não vejo jeito de chegar ao resultado que pretende :/

Comment: @JoãoMartins o que puderei fazer para você me perceber e ajudar? preciso mesmo muito de concluir isto o mais rápido possível

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90770/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-miguel-meireles).

Answer (score 1):

Tentei simular aqui e pelo que vi esta faltando informações!
estou postando a query aqui e você me fala oque falta obrigado.

```
   declare @Tecnicos table(IDGestor int, NomeGestor varchar(10), Email varchar(20))
insert into @Tecnicos values (13,'pd','hh@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (14,'pf','ee@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (15,'fp','gt@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (16,'fd','ww@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (17,'ff','kl@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (18,'gg','as@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (19,'lider','lider@ssss.com')
insert into @Tecnicos values (20,'lider2','lider@ssss.com')

declare @Reclamacoes table(IDGestor int, Resolvido bit)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (13,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (14,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (15,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (16,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (17,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (18,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (19,0)
insert into @Reclamacoes values (12,0)

declare @Vendedor table(IDGestor int, NomeGestor varchar(20))
insert into @Vendedor values (13,'pd')
insert into @Vendedor values (14,'pf')
insert into @Vendedor values (15,'fp')
insert into @Vendedor values (16,'fd')
insert into @Vendedor values (17,'ff')
insert into @Vendedor values (18,'gg')
insert into @Vendedor values (19,'lider')
insert into @Vendedor values (20,'lider2')

SELECT r.IDGestor , vs.NomeGestor AS EmailGestor ,ts.Email AS EmailLider
FROM @Reclamacoes R
INNER JOIN @Tecnicos TS ON R.IdGestor = TS.IDGestor
INNER JOIN @Vendedor VS ON R.IdGestor = VS.IDGestor
WHERE R.Resolvido = 0
ORDER BY r.IDGestor
```